# Register iWidgets in WebSphere Portal, registered but portlet not visible

Tags: websphere-7, websphere-portal

I am new to iWidgets, I am trying to use iWidgets in WebSphere Portal. So far, I am able to create iWidget and register it, and added it on portal page.

```
/ConfigEngine.sh register-iwidget-definition -DIWidgetDefinition=/HelloIWidget/HelloWidget.xml
```

The first one -HelloIWidget was succesfully registered and added as portlet on portal page.But when I try to register another iWidget, the registeration task is succesful but I am not able to see it in the portlets section of portal server admin console.

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine>ConfigEngine.bat register-iwidget-defin
ition -DIWidgetDefinition=/MyHelloWidgetEVSUB/HelloEventSub.xml -DPortalAdminPwd
=wpsadmin -DWasPassword=wpsadmin
Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
5724-E76, 5724-E77, 5655-M44
(C) Copyright IBM Corp.  All Rights Reserved.

Running Configuration Engine task 'register-iwidget-definition'
propertiesPath is ConfigEngine_temp.prop
rootDir is C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine
Executing native2ascii with native encoding 'Cp1252': ConfigEngine_temp.prop_ ->
 ConfigEngine_temp_ascii.prop_
Native2ascii execution was successful!
Loading system properties from ConfigEngine_temp_ascii.prop_
ConfigEngine: setting system property server.root=C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
ConfigEngine: setting system property was.repository.root=C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_pr
ofile/config
ConfigEngine: setting system property JAVA_HOME=C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java
ConfigEngine: setting system property CellName=IBMNC9REKB1JLG
ConfigEngine: setting system property ws.ext.dirs=C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/jav
a/lib;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib;C:/IBM/W
ebSphere/AppServer/installedChannels;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext;C:/IBM/W
ebSphere/AppServer/web/help;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/co
m.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime;./lib;./shared/app
ConfigEngine: setting system property jvmArgFor64bit=-D64bit.args=none
ConfigEngine: setting system property NodeName=IBMNC9REKB1JLG
ConfigEngine: setting system property local.node=IBMNC9REKB1JLG
ConfigEngine: setting system property was.root=C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
ConfigEngine: setting system property was.install.root=C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServe
r
ConfigEngine: setting system property cfg.trace=C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/Conf
igEngine/log/ConfigTrace.log
ConfigEngine: setting system property local.cell=IBMNC9REKB1JLG
RegistrySynchronized: true
Registry already in sync
[05/07/13 16:52:12.485 SGT] ssl.default.password.in.use.CWPKI0041W
[05/07/13 16:52:12.803 SGT] ssl.disable.url.hostname.verification.CWPKI0027I
[05/07/13 16:52:12.845 SGT] Client code attempting to load security configuratio
n
[05/07/13 16:52:20.445 SGT] Client code attempting to load security configuratio
n
Created admin client: com.ibm.ws.management.AdminClientImpl@11f311f3
Created config Service Proxy: com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.ConfigS
erviceProxy@7bda7bda
CELL: IBMNC9REKB1JLG
NODE: IBMNC9REKB1JLG
Websphere:_Websphere_Config_Data_Type=Registry,_Websphere_Config_Data_Id=cells/I
BMNC9REKB1JLG|registry.xml#Registry_1365043526167,_WEBSPHERE_CONFIG_SESSION=anon
ymous1367916748358
[05/07/13 16:52:29.971 SGT] WSVR0801I
loaded registry from WAS: registry.xml
wasUserHome now set to: C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile
Buildfile: base_dynamic.xml
Trying to override old definition of task property
Trying to override old definition of task sleep
Trying to override old definition of task java
Trying to override old definition of task exec

cleanup-work-dir:
Tue May 07 16:52:49 SGT 2013
     [echo] Cleaning up...
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\w
ork
     [echo] Done.
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\work

action-set-time-property:
Tue May 07 16:52:49 SGT 2013

action-init-zos:
Tue May 07 16:52:49 SGT 2013
     [echo] Setting property isZos to ${isZos}
     [echo] Setting property jvmArgForZos to -Dzos.argsconversion=none

action-set-managed-node-flag:
Tue May 07 16:52:49 SGT 2013
     [echo] Is this a Managed Node ?  false

action-set-conntype-property:
Tue May 07 16:52:50 SGT 2013
     [echo] wsadminConnType set to: SOAP

init-cfg-files:
Tue May 07 16:52:50 SGT 2013
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\w
ork
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\work
     [copy] Copying 5 files to C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\w
ork
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\wo
rk
     [copy] Copying 7 files to C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\w
ork

set-wsadmin-scripting-classpath-in-jacl-properties-1:
Tue May 07 16:52:52 SGT 2013
     [echo] C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile
     [echo] wsadmin.properties com.ibm.ws.scripting.classpath:           '${com.
ibm.ws.scripting.classpath}'
     [echo] com.ibm.ws.scripting.classpath.initial:                      'C:/IBM
/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngine/lib/wkplc.misc.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.j
ar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/base/wp.base/shared/app/wp.base.jar;C:/IBM/WebS
phere/PortalServer/shared/app/wp.base.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngi
ne/shared/app/lotusworkplacelib/lwp.clbcmpAPI.jar'

set-wsadmin-scripting-classpath-in-jacl-properties-2:
Tue May 07 16:52:52 SGT 2013
     [echo] jacl.properties com.ibm.ws.scripting.classpath:              'C:/IBM
/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngine/lib/wkplc.misc.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.j
ar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/base/wp.base/shared/app/wp.base.jar;C:/IBM/WebS
phere/PortalServer/shared/app/wp.base.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngi
ne/shared/app/lotusworkplacelib/lwp.clbcmpAPI.jar'
     [echo] jacl.properties com.ibm.ws.scripting.port:              '10025'
     [echo] jacl.properties com.ibm.ws.scripting.host:              'local.porta
l7.com'

set-wsadmin-scripting-classpath-in-jacl-properties:
Tue May 07 16:52:52 SGT 2013

action-init-cfg-files-zos:
Tue May 07 16:52:52 SGT 2013

setup-additional-init-files:
Tue May 07 16:52:52 SGT 2013

init:
Tue May 07 16:52:52 SGT 2013
     [echo] 2013-05-07-04-52
Trying to override old definition of task wplc-modify-server
Trying to override old definition of task wplc-create-server
Trying to override old definition of task wplc-remove-server

set-properties:
Tue May 07 16:52:57 SGT 2013
[setproperty] Property PortalAdminId was set to wpsadmin
[setproperty] Property PortalAdminGroupId was set to wpsadmins
[setproperty] Property WpsDocReviewer was set to ${WpsDocReviewer}
[setproperty] Property WpsContentAdministrators was set to ${WpsContentAdministr
ators}
[setproperty] Property UserSuffix was set to ${LDAPUserSuffix},${LDAPSuffix}
[setproperty] Property GroupSuffix was set to ${LDAPGroupSuffix},${LDAPSuffix}

action-pre-config:
Tue May 07 16:52:58 SGT 2013
     [echo] executing pre-configuration tasks
   [isWas7] overwriting previous definition of property: null
   [isWas7] +++value of property is 7.0.0.11

action-set-config:
Tue May 07 16:53:00 SGT 2013
     [echo] executing set-configuration tasks
     [echo] contains@empty_string@

wait-for-sync-to-complete:
Tue May 07 16:53:00 SGT 2013

start-portal-server:
Tue May 07 16:53:00 SGT 2013

set-instance-properties:
Tue May 07 16:53:01 SGT 2013

action-start-portal-server-service:
Tue May 07 16:53:01 SGT 2013
   [logmsg] [05/07/13 16:53:05.561 SGT] EJPCA3163I: Starting Server "WebSphere_P
ortal"
     [echo] Port '10039' is in use on host 'localhost'
     [echo] An instance of the server 'WebSphere_Portal' may already be running

action-set-managed-node-flag:
Tue May 07 16:53:07 SGT 2013
     [echo] Is this a Managed Node ?  false

action-set-conntype-property:
Tue May 07 16:53:07 SGT 2013
     [echo] wsadminConnType set to: SOAP

set-wsadmin-scripting-classpath-in-jacl-properties-1:
Tue May 07 16:53:08 SGT 2013
     [echo] C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile
     [echo] wsadmin.properties com.ibm.ws.scripting.classpath:           '${com.
ibm.ws.scripting.classpath}'
     [echo] com.ibm.ws.scripting.classpath.initial:                      'C:/IBM
/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngine/lib/wkplc.misc.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.j
ar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/base/wp.base/shared/app/wp.base.jar;C:/IBM/WebS
phere/PortalServer/shared/app/wp.base.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngi
ne/shared/app/lotusworkplacelib/lwp.clbcmpAPI.jar'

set-wsadmin-scripting-classpath-in-jacl-properties-2:
Tue May 07 16:53:08 SGT 2013
     [echo] jacl.properties com.ibm.ws.scripting.classpath:              'C:/IBM
/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngine/lib/wkplc.misc.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.j
ar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/base/wp.base/shared/app/wp.base.jar;C:/IBM/WebS
phere/PortalServer/shared/app/wp.base.jar;C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngi
ne/shared/app/lotusworkplacelib/lwp.clbcmpAPI.jar'
     [echo] jacl.properties com.ibm.ws.scripting.port:              '10025'
     [echo] jacl.properties com.ibm.ws.scripting.host:              'local.porta
l7.com'

set-wsadmin-scripting-classpath-in-jacl-properties:
Tue May 07 16:53:08 SGT 2013

register-iwidget-definition:
Tue May 07 16:53:08 SGT 2013
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server] Task parameters:
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]   Global attributes:
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]     server="WebSphere_Portal"
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]     osarch="amd64"
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]     node="IBMNC9REKB1JLG"
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]     pathseparator=";"
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]     engineinstalllocation="C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_pr
ofile/ConfigEngine"
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]     cell="IBMNC9REKB1JLG"

[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]   Instance attributes (Set 1 of 1):
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]     endPointName="SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS"
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server]     attribute=[ *** NONE_SPECIFIED *** ]
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server] end point: SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS found
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server] Settings the host: local.portal7.com as ant prope
rty: ${hostInJMX}
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server] Settings the port: 10025 as ant property: ${portI
nJMX}
[wplc-get-host-port-in-server] Status = Complete
     [echo] Determined soap host: local.portal7.com
     [echo] Determined soap connector: 10025

iseries-switch-to-was-user:
Tue May 07 16:53:16 SGT 2013
  [wsadmin] WASX7209I: Connected to process "WebSphere_Portal" on node IBMNC9REK
B1JLG using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess
  [wsadmin] WASX7303I: The following options are passed to the scripting environ
ment and are available as arguments that are stored in the argv variable: "[C:/I
BM/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngine, IWidgetDefinition=/MyHelloWidgetEVSUB/Hell
oEventSub.xml, IWidgetCatalog=${IWidgetCatalog}, PortletDefinition=${PortletDefi
nition}, PortletUniqueName=${PortletUniqueName}]"
  [wsadmin] false
  [wsadmin] logged in as "uid=wpsadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm"
  [wsadmin] [05/07/13 16:54:16.715 SGT] EJPXD0001I
  [wsadmin] EJPFD0085I: Report started at 5/7/13 4:54 PM.EJPFD0087I: Object [Obj
ectIDImpl 'Z3_J1RDFTVJ849QD0IFUPU3HP1046', PORTLET_DEFINITION, VP: 0, [Domain: r
el], DB: 0000-33ECF6FA9F8824DD807C3EFB117300C4] processed successfully.EJPFD0086
I: Report completetd at 5/7/13 4:54 PM.
  [wsadmin] success

delete-temp-dirs:
Tue May 07 16:54:25 SGT 2013
   [delete] Deleting: C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\work\was\w
p_portal.properties
   [delete] Deleting: C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\properties\wkplc_
comp_ascii.properties
   [delete] Deleting: C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\properties\wkplc_
ascii.properties
   [delete] Deleting 5 files from C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\prope
rties

cleanup-work-dir:
Tue May 07 16:54:26 SGT 2013
     [echo] Cleaning up...
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\w
ork
     [echo] Done.
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\ConfigEngine\config\work

action-post-config:
Tue May 07 16:54:26 SGT 2013
     [echo] executing post-configuration tasks

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 47 seconds
isIseries currently set to: null
uploading registry
Created admin client: com.ibm.ws.management.AdminClientImpl@11f311f3
Created config Service Proxy: com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.ConfigS
erviceProxy@5b905b9
CELL: IBMNC9REKB1JLG
NODE: IBMNC9REKB1JLG
Websphere:_Websphere_Config_Data_Type=Registry,_Websphere_Config_Data_Id=cells/I
BMNC9REKB1JLG|registry.xml#Registry_1365043526167,_WEBSPHERE_CONFIG_SESSION=anon
ymous1367916867190




update-registry-sync-property:
Tue May 07 16:54:28 SGT 2013
     [echo] updated RegistrySynchronized in file wkplc.properties with value: tr
ue
Return Value: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iWidgets get registered by cloning a generic iWidget Portlet and assigning your URL to it. Usually it also gets a weird name. Since all portlets are shown in the order they were added, go to the Administration - Portlets and there to the last page. Most probably your widget is there. I was unable to find a way to rename the widget, so I made a copy of it and when doing that you can give a new name to your widget. Afterwards the original widget can be removed.

Please note that iWidget Portlet requires widget_container capability, which is provided by mm_enabler module. It is not included into the theme by default. It can be included either by modifying profile json files like described here http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/8.0.0/doc/en_us/PT800ACD001/dev/themeopt_add_oobmod.html
or by using add-theme-modules COnfigEngine command, which does exactly the same.
I also had to change a page theme profile in order to get my widget added, otherwise I always got this missing widget_container 2.1 capability error message.

Comment: add-theme-modules is only for WP8, sorry about a confusion. But editing profile json files is always possible but you will need to have a WebDAV client. Also check if pre-req modules are included. For WP8 I used these tables http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/8.0.0/doc/en_us/PT800ACD001/dev/themeopt_oob.html